# How to appy one javascript function to multiple textbox onfocus event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, background-color

I have two javascript functions to change background color on enter and leave events.

```
    function ColoronEnter()
      { 
        var txt1 = document.getElementById("<%=txtID1.ClientID%>");
       txt1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }

      function ColoronLeave()
      { 
        var txt2 = document.getElementById("<%=txtID1.ClientID%>");
       txt2.style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
```

I am calling them as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtID1" runat="server" MaxLength="20" AutoCompleteType="FirstName"  onfocus="ColoronEnter()" onblur="ColoronLeave()" ></asp:TextBox>
```

It is working well. But I want to apply one javascript function to all my textboxes. I have tried something like

```
        function onEnter(_input)
       {
        var input = _input;
        document.getElementById(input).style.backgroundColor ="yellow"; 
       }  
       function onLeave(_input)
       {
        var input = _input;
        document.getElementById(input).style.backgroundColor =""; 
       }
```

trying to call them as

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtID2" runat="server" onfocus="onEnter(txtID2)" onblur="onLeave(txtID2)"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtID3" runat="server" onfocus="onEnter(txtID3)" onblur="onLeave(txtID3)"></asp:TextBox>
```

It is throwing an error as

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined.
```

How can I call one function to all my textboxes. Thank in advance.

Comment: you can use this keyword instead of txtID2 and txtID3 or enclose your control's Ids in single quotation mark like onfocus="onEnter('txtID2')".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtID2" runat="server" onfocus="onEnter(this)" onblur="onLeave(this)"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtID3" runat="server" onfocus="onEnter(this)" onblur="onLeave(this)"></asp:TextBox>


    function onEnter(_input)
   {
     _input.style.backgroundColor ="yellow"; 
   }  
   function onLeave(_input)
   {
     _input.style.backgroundColor =""; 
   }
```

If you don't have any restrictions to use jQuery, use [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event to handle this.